# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, debugging, types

i tried to make a function that sort an array based from it's length

```
function sortingByLength(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i + 1].length > array[i].length) {
      smol = array[i];
      array[i] = array[i + 1];
      array[i + 1] = smol;
      i = -1;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

let testPack = ["Chicken", "Monkeys", "Foxy"];
```

while it had no error whatsoever, it shows

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

and the error pointer shows

```
c:\......................\Special-Training-1\9.js:18
    if (array[i + 1].length > array[i].length) {
                     ^
```

i tried to debug it with node in vscode run and debug, it was doing things as normal, all parameter read normal. i watched grouping, array[i].length and array[i+1].length. i read there's possibilities that i had same variable down in line it can happens but no, i don't have any variable named 'array' or 'length'

i did try, just removing the length at all. but it doens't work as i need to compare the length and rearrange it inside the array itself.

for notes: i can't use proper built in function such as forEach, every, splice, slice and such. however i can use for loop and for.. of. and i can't use any array built in besides .push()

Comment: can you share what are u passing to the function? do a console log of `array` before the `for`

Comment: Its because you are going out of bounds in the array, since you are using ```array[i+1]``` and ```i < array.length```. For the last iteration, ```i+1``` will be out of bounds and undefined. For this scenario, update the condition to ```i<array.length-1```

Comment: wow, now i missed that. thanks for your answer sir. it works fine with numbers, i thought it will works fine with string too

Answer (score 0):

i missed the limitation on the length. thanks for vicki on pointing that out. i did this in number, and it works just fine. so i reused this in array of strings, and it failed. i used

> i < array.length - 1

and it works just fine